# Do these red stop signs apply to aircraft or only to vehicles?

Tags: airport-design, airport-markings

I mean; do planes also see these signs on their way to runway? Or just cars and other vehicles encounter this stop sign on their service road or interconnection roads that are assigned to them? [image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

No, those signs do not apply to aircraft. They are for vehicles and marks entry to the maneuvering area.

Comment: So vehicles can see these marks in the borders of apron right? Because the maneuvering area does not comprise apron.

Comment: I mean it will depend on the local airport. But generally speaking, since the apron is not part of the maneuvering area, a vehicle does NOT need clearance from tower to drive on the apron

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Now, I see what you did emphasize, thank you! And you are ATC too; I am cadet ATC right now. I would like to communicate with you on social media if you want it too. my Instagram account is written in my profile. Later,

Comment: Hey Volkan. I'm not really active on social media, but feel free to drop me a chat on this site

Comment: Confirm Mr. Hougaard; later!